# How to add strapi images to next.js public folder

Tags: next.js, strapi

I'm building website with Next.js and strapi.

I'm using build + export in next.js

I need all images used in project to be put in next public folder so i don't have to host strapi dashboard.

How to achieve this so:

- every image from strapi used in next project is put in public folder
- every url is changed from: localhost:1337/uploads/... to url like when using image from next/public folder